# C++ balanced tree / call order in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, machine-learning, tree-balancing

I'm writing an implementation of a CART tree at the moment, which is binary tree used in machine learning. It is trained recursively as sketched in the following code:

```
struct Node
{
    Node * parent;
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
};

void train(Node* node)
{
    //perform training algorithm on node

    train(node->left);
    train(node->right);
}
```

Now assume I restrict the number of traing iterations to a chosen value, say `nTraining=4`.

Then, by unrolling the recursive function calls, I expect that only the `left` branch is evolved. So the first four calls are:

```
    train(node);
    train(node->left);
    train(node->left->left);
    train(node->left->left->left);
    //only now train(node->left->left->right); would follow
```

which gives a completely unbalanced tree looking like

```
          O
         / \
        O   O
       / \
      O   O
     / \
    O   O
   / \
  O   O
```

**Can anybody please suggest a way by which I can further use the recursive training approach and still obtain a balanced tree?**

Comment: Do you mean keep the tree balanced throughout the recursive process?

Comment: @JoelCornett: it would suffice if the end result (after `nTraining` iterations) is balanced.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you want to stick to recursive approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, don't use recursion (DFS). Use BFS, that is queue instead, so the tree is traversed level by level:

```
std::queue<Node*> q;
Node* root;
q.push(root);
for (int i = 0; i < nTraining; ++i) {
    Node* node = q.front();
    q.pop();
    train(node);
    q.push(node->left);
    q.push(node->right);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the good answer, I'll probably have to switch to this approach (otherwise I'd have to use stopping rules which consider not only the single node, but rather the whole tree).

Comment: just for completeness: the `std::queue` thing is only to forbid training later nodes, isn't it? One could use as well a `std::deque` and pop it repeatedly?

Comment: @davidhigh yes, you could use `std::deque` with `push_back` and `pop_front`. In fact, `std::queue` is a wrapper around `std::deque` by default.